# Azure AKS APT Clear-Containers Key Expired

Tags: azure, ubuntu, gnupg, apt, azure-aks

I am seeing the following error when I try to apt update.

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/clearcontainers:/clear-containers-3/xUbuntu_16.04  Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1562449942
W: Failed to fetch http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/clearcontainers:/clear-containers-3/xUbuntu_16.04/Release.gpg  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1562449942
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/clearcontainers:/clear-containers-3/xUbuntu_16.04/

I have tried to delete the key and update again, uses same key and does not work.
I have tried to get that key from common servers but they do not have it (e.g.  pgp.mit.edu and keys.gnupg.net).

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: rebuild the nodes?

Comment: Are you kidding me? Rebuild nodes to fix an apt key issue? No I did obviously not try that :) Please explain the reasoning behind that comment, e.g. why that should solve the issue.

Comment: why not? i dont have those issues on my nodes. its easier to rebuild stuff from code (or in this case just update k8s to newer version, which would recreate the nodes) than try and troubleshoot something. unless its always coming back

Comment: Where do you get the error? What system do you use? Ubuntu or OpenSUSE?

Comment: Ubuntu as provided in the AKS default installation. Linux aks-agentpool-10982034-0 4.15.0-1040-azure #44-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 21 14:24:01 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: As I know, the AKS nodes do not have the public IP, so I do not think you can update the packages in the nodes if you do not associate a public IP to them.

Comment: It does not matter that they do not have public IPs depending on your setup. As you can see from the initial comment this is only related to one repository, not anything else.I rebuilt nodes but it did not solve my issue with the clearcontainers repo.